# Evaporate propylene glycol

Tags: experimental-chemistry, drugs

I tried to make a cannabis infused e-liquid. I made a tincture with marijuana and vegetable glycerin, but it became to thick so a mixed in more propylene glycol than I'd originally planned. Now the e-liquid is to weak, not enough THC per milliliter.

My question is: can I just heat up the e-liquid to 115-123 degrees celsius and let the glycol evaporate over a long time, or is that temperature too low? I don't want to destroy the psychoactive chemicals in the e-liquid.

Best wishes.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. Personal medical questions are off-topic on Chemistry. We can not safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should always consult a doctor for medical advice.

Answer (score 2):

Let me reword the question:

Does $\Delta^9$-tetrahydrocannabinol (THC) significantly degrade when its solution in propylene glycol is heated to 115-123 °C?

This was somewhat answered in a study by *Michael A. Repka et al.* ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080%2F03639040500387914)) on the stability of THC embedded in a  hydroxypropylcellulose polymer matrix. When heating this system to 120 °C for 75-90 min, about 2.7% of the initial THC degraded. With other words, 97.20% remained unchanged.

Heating to higher temperatures did not lead to significantly higher degradation, but among the degradation products, the amount of cannabinol (CBN), the oxidation product of THC, was much higher here.

Technically, heating to ~120 °C seems to be no problem.

*You might want to check the reference given, have a look at the articles cited, compare toxicological data of THC and CBN and decide for yourself.*